# Find PostgreSQL server hostname on which it runs

Tags: postgresql, networking, postgresql-8.4

Is it possible to find the host on which the PostgreSQL Server runs ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SELECT inet_server_addr()`, but it'll return `NULL` if connection is established via Unix-domain socket.  And there's `inet_server_port()` which returns the port server is listening.